# memoir : adding vertical space below chapter entries in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, memoir, tocloft

I am trying to replicate, with the `memoir` class, a behaviour I managed to tackle with `tocloft` : in a Table of Contents containing chapters, I want the vertical space below the chapter entries to be larger than the default value. With `tocloft`, I used

```
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\par\addvspace{0.8em}}
```

I could not find any equivalent command in `memoir`, something like `\cftbeforechapterskip` but with "after" instead of "before".

Comment: You can do the same with `memoir` it is just called `\cftchapterafterpnum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memoir has most of the features from `tocloft` but often under slightly different macro names.

Here you can just use

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\renewcommand\cftchapterafterpnum{\par\addvspace{0.8em}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Test}

\section{test}
\end{document}
```

to get the same result, that is `chapter` instead of `chap`.